# set Azure Function Environment Variable for Nodejs Project

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

How to set Azure Function Environment Variable for development and production-ready code?

ExpressJS already provided Environment config file, how to set Azure Function Environment Variable?

Answer (score 12):

For development you can add variables in **local.settings.json** :

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",

    "host": "localhost",
  }
}
```

And use it with :

```
process.env["host"]
```

For production you can add a Configuration of the Application in :

[image]

[image]

And this will override the variables in **local.settings.json**

Comment: NB: for localhost development you will need to restart functions to pick up env var changes.

Answer (score 4):

Azure Functions provide us with a `local.settings.json` file where we can define these variables.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FOO": "-- Your Value --",
  }
}
```

You can access it from your code using `process.env["FOO"]`

Refer official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#environment-variables)

If you want the settings post deployment, when you publish the function use the `--publish-local-settings -i` switch during publishing.

[Docs for publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#publish)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Locally is working fine, but I want to set the same local.settings.json file setup when I deploy my azure function. is any way please guide me, thanks

Comment: Thank you so much it is helpful for me @HariHaran. Please also add some tips for production-related configuration with azure function Nodejs.